# SuiteCommerce Advance: Unable to get the Free Shipping Rule Rate 'Insufficient permissions' for Custom Service

Tags: service, netsuite, suitecommerce

1. We tried loading shipping item data with 'nlapiLoadRecord', Currently we have two methods available Standard & Express. We tried to load data for standard method as below  in Script Debugger.

   `​var standard = nlapiLoadRecord('shipitem',3);`

We are getting all fields of standard shipitem in Script Debugger, then we are fetching shipping rule value with

```
var standard_amount = standard.getFieldValues('freeifordertotalisoveramount');
```

2. Then we tried to load these same data using nlapiLoadRecord in our custom SuiteScript Model, we tried to call this method in our custom ShippingDetails.Model, and tried to fetched the data on cart page but it is giving us '**Insufficient permissions**' error massage. Please see below attached screenshot. nlapiLoadRecord('shipitem',3);  does not allow us to load data on front end.

[image]

Comment: have you created service for this?

Comment: Yes, I have created service & suiteScript model under SuiteScript folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is not case with your code, as you are trying to load shipping rate using SuiteScript Service and model this is perfect.

​`var standard = nlapiLoadRecord('shipitem',3);
var standard_amount = standard.getFieldValues('freeifordertotalisoveramount');`

This is completely related with **user's permission** i.e Roles Under Setup-->User/Roles-->Manage Roles   you are trying to fetch data of 'shippingitem' in this case you must need to check different permission

1. Check your Script Service is enabled, enabled for with out login in NS back end

**Most Imp:**
2. Check shipping item is added in permission under List i.e the role which you are using for Service, for that role you must need to set shipping item See below screen shot you will get more idea.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This works for me, I added he shipping item as shown in second image. Thanks.